# multer middleware not invoked

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to upload images using multer, I dont know why `upload.single()` is not invoked at all, below is the multer configuration with storage and filter settings.

```
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

---

Here is the route to call multer middleware.

```
router.post('/addnew',auth.isLoggedIn,upload.single('photo'),(req,res,next)=>{
  // console.log("name:",req.body.title,req.body.descp,req.body.price,req.body.imagePath );

  console.log('file:',req.files," & ",req.file);


}
```

---

Form control with file input and button.

```
<form action="/product/addnew"  method="post">
     <div class="form-group row">
         <label><input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" class="form-control"/></label>
       </div>

     <div class="form-group row">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You seem to lack the `enctype=multipart/form-data` on your form. Let me know if this solves your issue, I would post this as an answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still same..

Comment: How do you configure multer? Do you have something like `app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('photo'));` in your app configuration?

Comment: please have look on the snippets, it shows multer configuratin with storage and filter settings.

Comment: Are you sure that your auth is fine? Change `router.post('/addnew', auth.isLoggedIn, upload.single('photo'), (req,res,next)=>` into `router.post('/addnew', upload.single('photo'), (req,res,next)=>{` and see if it works?

Comment: yes, Auth is fine, I removed call to auth.isLoggedIn as suggested. still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and there is no solution on the internet, so I tried to figure it out and finally I realized that the problem is from `express-fileupload` module if I use the multer before the line where I set the `fileUpload` middleware which is `app.use(fileUpload());` it works fine and the multer middleware will be invoked without any problem, so I ended up to remove fileUpload module and everything works fine

Answer (score -1):

**if You need Solution then you can use this one -**

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'./uploads');
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }   
});

var filefilter = function(req,file,cb){ 

         if(file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpeg|jpg)$/))
            {
            return cb(null,true);     
            }
        else{
             return  cb(new Error(('in image only image is allowed')));
            }

}    
var upload = multer({storage : storage,limits : {
    filesize :1024*1024*5
    },fileFilter :filefilter
});

module.exports = upload;
```

---

```
router.post('/addnew',auth.isLoggedIn,upload.single('photo'),(req,res,next)=>{
  // console.log("name:",req.body.title,req.body.descp,req.body.price,req.body.imagePath );

  console.log('file:',req.files," & ",req.file);


}
```